# remove the cross button on FB.ui dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook ios sdk, How can i remove the top left cross button on the popup ? I tried to remove the image in resource bundle , but even the cross is not there, you can still click the top left corner and cancel the dialog...

The reason why i want to remove it is because when you click that cross, the callback function won't get called.... I just wanna user click "cancel" or "share" which for me can be easily detected by looking in to the callback function

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running Hackbook in version 3.1.1 of the iOS SDK, clicking on the top-left corner results in "dialogDidNotComplete" being called on the dialog delegate.  Are you handling this selector?